# Automapper "Error mapping types" error when joining ICollection table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, entity-framework, automapper

In an Angular project based on ASP.NET MVC and EF, I have the following entities as shown below:

Note: There is no error if I don't add a file attachment. But adding a file causing this error during mapping.

***Ticket.cs :***

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Summary { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    //code omitted for brevity 

    public virtual ICollection<FileAttachment> FileAttachments { get; set; }
}
```

***TicketViewModel.cs :***

```
public class TicketViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //code omitted for brevity 

    public virtual ICollection<FileAttachmentViewModel> FileAttachments { get; set; }
}
```

***FileAttachmentViewModel.cs :***

```
public class FileAttachmentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TicketId { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public byte[] FileData { get; set; }

    //code omitted for brevity 

    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the mapping and the Save method where I encounter "Error mapping types. Mapping types: TicketViewModel -> Ticket..." error.

***Service.cs :***

```
public TicketViewModel Save(TicketViewModel model)
{
    //here I encounter the error while mapping TicketViewModel to Ticket
    var record = model.MapEntity<Ticket>();

    //code omitted for brevity 
}
```

***Mapping.cs :***

```
CreateMap<Ticket, TicketViewModel>();    
CreateMap<TicketViewModel, Ticket>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FileAttachments, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.FileAttachments);


CreateMap<FileAttachment, FileAttachmentViewModel>();
CreateMap<FileAttachmentViewModel, FileAttachment>();
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful to also have the definition of your Ticket class with at least its own definition of the property FileAttachments. 
It could have something to do with the fact that your FileAttachments property type is an interface. You don't have any mapping for the FileAttachmentViewModel type, which is a requirement to map one generic collection to another. I assume you have a property of the type FileAttachment, not FileAttachmentViewModel in your Ticket class. Hence AutoMapper gives you an exception.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I added Ticket class and mapping for FileAttachmentViewModel. FileAttachments property type is NOT an interface and YES I have a property of the type FileAttachment, not FileAttachmentViewModel in your Ticket class ( I think it is true way). But still the same error.  Any idea?